# AWS: The CIDR '10.30.1.0/24' conflicts with another subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am just learning AWS, super new so bear with me. I have tried messing around with the code for a while and I just have no idea. Trying to write a simple Cloudformation template of a VPC.

I keep getting error "The CIDR '10.30.1.0/24' conflicts with another subnet (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSubnet.Conflict; Request ID: ea17de71-6dc2-46d2-bda4-dda6ff9e0980; Proxy: null)"

Here is my code:

```
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment Name
    Type: String
  VpcName:
    Type: String
  VpcCIDR:
    Description: VPC CIDR
    Type: String
    Default: 10.30.0.0/16
  NumberOfSubnets:
    Description: Number of Subnets to be created
    Type: String
    Default: 4
  SubnetOffset:
    Description: Offest of Subnet from CIDR
    Type: String
    Default: 8

Outputs:
  VPC:
    Description: VPC
    Value: !Ref VPC
  VpcCIDR:
      Description: VPC CIDR
      Value: !Ref VpcCIDR
  PublicSubnets:
      Description: Public Subnets
      Value: !Join [ ",", [!Ref PublicSubnet1, !Ref PublicSubnet2]]
  PrivateSubnets:
      Description: Private Subenets
      Value: !Join [ ",", [!Ref PublicSubnet1, !Ref PublicSubnet2]]
  PublicSubnet1:
      Description: Public Subnet AZ1
      Value: !Ref PublicSubnet1
  PublicSubnet2:
      Description: Public Subnet AZ2
      Value: !Ref PublicSubnet2
  PrivateSubnet1:
      Description: Private Subnet AZ1
      Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
  PrivateSubnet2:
      Description: Private Subnet AZ2
      Value: !Ref PrivateSubnet2
  PublicRouteTable:
      Description: Public Route Table
      Value: !Ref PublicRouteTable
  PrivateRouteTable:
      Description: Private Route Table
      Value: !Ref PrivateRouteTable

Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCIDR
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}

  InternetGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [0, !Cidr [!Ref VpcCIDR, !Ref NumberOfSubnets, !Ref SubnetOffset]]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}-public-1

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [1, !Cidr [!Ref VpcCIDR, !Ref NumberOfSubnets, !Ref SubnetOffset]]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}-public-2

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [2, !Cidr [!Ref VpcCIDR, !Ref NumberOfSubnets, !Ref SubnetOffset]]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}-private-1

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [1, !Cidr [!Ref VpcCIDR, !Ref NumberOfSubnets, !Ref SubnetOffset]]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}-private-2
  NatGateway1EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway2EIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  NatGateway1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway1EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  NatGateway2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt NatGateway2EIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${Environment} Public Routes

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PublicSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicSubnet2RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${Environment} Private Routes (AZ1)

  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1

  PrivateSubnet1RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. thats because your PublicSubnet2 and PrivateSubnet2 are getting the same subnet CIDR value.

if you look at your template you have the same value for both subnets which is `!Select [1, !Cidr [!Ref VpcCIDR, !Ref NumberOfSubnets, !Ref SubnetOffset]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `PrivateSubnet2` should be :

```
  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Select [3, !Cidr [!Ref VpcCIDR, !Ref NumberOfSubnets, !Ref SubnetOffset]]
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub ${VpcName}-${Environment}-private-2
```

Originally, the `CidrBlock` was a duplicate of the one from `PublicSubnet2`.